# Error library libUartLib.a (print Bluetooth)

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth

Has anyone developed with the **libUartLib.a** library?

Because I have the following error:

```
-[CBCentralManager retrieveConnectedPeripherals]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15e868d0
2015-10-02 17:13:29.265 DAPPER[2639:1705276] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CBCentralManager retrieveConnectedPeripherals]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15e868d0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x27a5186b 0x394bedff 0x27a57035 0x27a54c8f 0x279842b8 0x1018a3 0x27714a55 0x22cdbf 0x22cdab 0x231829 0x27a14595 0x27a12a8f 0x279651e9 0x27964fdd 0x30bc9af9 0x2bbca18d 0x1002b9 0x39be9873)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCentralManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CBCentralManager/retrieveConnectedPeripherals) you will that that method was deprecated in iOS 7 and has been removed in iOS 9. The replacement is `retrieveConnectedPeripheralsSithServices` so you either need an updated version of the library or to update it yourself if the author hasn't done so or to identify an alternative.